# how to send email into gmail from laravel5.5 without providing smtp_password?

Tags: gmail, laravel-5.5

I have a form for making appointment. Whenever users make a appointment the details of users must be sent to official gmail. How can i do it ? Does i need to provide gmail password in environment file. But my client doesn't want to share his password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This will help

```
\Mail::send('appoiment', $data, function($message) use($email) {
                $message->from('email@asd.com', 'Asd Man');
                $message->to($email);
                $message->subject('Tittle');
            });
            $this->info("Email was sent to: " . $email);
```

Comment: do i need to provide email and password in .env file

Comment: Yes! @AnandMainali

Comment: but my client doesn't want to share his password. Is there other way to solve this problem??

Comment: You can make a dummy acc. Ex, support@email.com

Comment: Need to create an account by which you can send the emails to their accounts.

Comment: thank u i created a webmail account in cpanel and used it for sending mail.